# Powershell Remote Desktop Connection specifying user and password

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, powershell

How do you specify a user when using the mstsc command in powershell? While I can specify the server, I cannot specify a user.

Let's assume Server name = server01, User name = Test, Password = PW

**Example 1**
    mstsc /v:server01 /user server01\test /password PW

This only brings up the "Remote Desktop Connection Usage" help menu.

**Example 2**
    mstsc /v:server01

This works, bringing up the normal RDP connection prompt for User & password.

**Example 3**
    mstsc /v:server01 /user server01\test

Even trying to just specify the user fails, bringing up the help menu again.

Some website articles on powershell suggest using "Connect-RDP" or "Connect-Mstsc" instead of just "mstsc" as per above examples, but this only brings up an error code. My knowledge of powershell is very basic, so I'm probably making a simple mistake somewhere.

Comment: Using this script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-Mstsc-Open-RDP-2064b10b/view/Discussions and running the command `Connect-Mstsc -ComputerName 18.186.48.107:3389 -User workpc\Yisroel -Password YisroelGithub -Verbose`

Comment: Yisroel, this still brings up an error Connect-Mstsc is not recognised

Comment: It is not a built-in command. You need to download the *Connect-Mstsc.ps1* script file from the link I mentioned. Then *cd* to the script file location (`cd C:\Users\Yisroel\Downloads`) then run `. .\Connect-Mstsc.ps1` and then that script with the details

Comment: Yisroel, still not working sorry. Downloaded script, and ran as above. Error: " ...cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled". Ran as admin: "Set-ExecutionPolicy -executionpolicy undefined". Still getting error

Comment: To run a script from anywhere you need to first run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the "Remote Desktop Connection Usage" help menu, there is no switch like "/user" or "/password".

Please try

cmdkey /generic:"server01" /user:"test" /pass:"PW"

Then used **mstsc /v:server01** to connect to the server.

Comment: @Yisroel Tech and V_V, both methods worked once I unticked "Always ask for credentials" in Remote Desktop Connection settings.

Comment: Preferably you should use `cmdkey /add:TERMSRV/server01 /user:Test /pass:PW`
And if you want the credentials to be deleted after mstsc has launched you can do this by invoking the command `cmdkey /delete:TERMSRV/server01`

Answer (score 2):

I want to note here that if your domain administrators have disabled caching of credentials none of the suggested answers will work.

Comment: exactly what i'm having happen. so this is useless then

Comment: Yes.  About your only option then is to download a free macro recorder and let that do the login for you.  Of course then your password is stored plaintext on your machine.

Comment: no there is another way - i've seen a product called Eggplant do it. I just don't know how it does it.

Answer (score 1):

It has been said before, but I'd just like to add a fully working, batch-ready example that I use when I need to log in to so several user's accounts on a simple (i.e. the same password for all users) terminal server, e.g. when I need to make certain changes to each user's environment.

```
For %f in (user1 user2 user3) do cmdkey /add:TERMSRV/servername /user:domain\%f /pass:commonpassword & mstsc /v:servername & ping 127.0.0.1 & cmdkey /delete:TERMSRV/servername
```

(replace "servername", "domain", "commonpassword" and the usernames in the for-loop as needed. You may need to open MSTSC once without parameters to set the default parameters as needed and then save the settings.)